# Using extra flags from generator commands in CMake scripts

Tags: cmake

How can you write a CMakeLists.txt script for CMake such that targets in the generator files use extra flags supplied in the generator command?  For example,

Commands:

> cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"
>
> make MY_FLAGS="-Dfoo -Bar"

CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable ( MyApp main.cpp )
# How to reference MY_FLAGS in compile, link commands for MyApp target?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the Makefile variable dereference syntax in your flags:

```
add_definitions("$(MY_FLAGS)")
```

I used `add_definitions` because flags added by this don't get passed to the linker. You can experiment with putting such references into `CMAKE_<Lang>_FLAGS` and related variables/properties instead.

In have no idea how non-Makefile generators will deal with something like this, however. Perhaps an enclosing `if(CMAKE_GENERATOR ...)` would be a good idea.

Comment: If he sets the flags to an env var in the specific call of cmake and make, [ENV](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/ENV.html) could be useful to read those.